# Adding 0x api to a wallet andriod, apple OS, chrome and desktop wallet

Tags: 0x

I have a few questions I hope somebody could clarify for me.

- Is it possible to add the 0x API to a digital crypto wallet? if so what is the requirement for the underlying system?
- Does it cost anything or can I monetize it myself? (earning a fee from people using the system within the wallet)

Sincerely
Frederik

Answer (score 0):

It is completely free to integrate with 0x API, you can do it by simply making a request to our hosted 0x API service when the user is looking to swap tokens.

We allow for specifying optional `buyTokenPercentageFee` and `feeRecipient` parameters so you can easily monetize to whatever extent you'd like.

For more information see the [0x API docs](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote)